# Format new Date().toGMTString() to local date and a human readable format

Tags: javascript, string, date, formatting

I'm using javascript and hav a date string in GMT fromat, for example:

```
"Mon, 02 Nov 2020 15:12:31 GMT"
```

is there is a method to convert the string to a local date format and a human readable format ?

Comment: Is that not readable enough? You see the month, day, weekday, year, and time

Comment: I'm not joking I'm being serious because I don't know what you mean by readable

Comment: new Date ("Mon, 02 Nov 2020 15:12:31 GMT");

Comment: You could get the date.ToString then append with date.ToStringTime to get a very nice human readable string

Comment: new Date ("Mon, 02 Nov 2020 15:12:31 GMT").toDateString() or use the various Date methods to get what you want. getMonth(), .getYear()...etc.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys, this is enough for me.